# How to pull other people's (github) commits into your tree?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have a GitHub repo.

Someone has forked this repo and has a few good commits which I would like to pull in.

They do not answer email, so I cannot ask them to send a pull request upstream to my repo.

How can I get these commits into my repo, while preserving their authorship, etc.

Command-line git solutions, or GitHub UI solutions are both welcome.

Comment: Can you add it a second remote, and then merge/cherry-pick as needed?

Comment: Find out the branch in their fork that contains the commits. In your local clone run `git fetch <their_fork_url> <branch>:<some_branch_name>`. And then you could run `git push origin <some_branch_name>` to push the ref to your repo.

Comment: Did my answer help you? Was that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pull request and compare across forks on the GitHub website. Follow this simple Step-by-Step:

- Go into your repository
- Click on new pull request
- Click on compare across forks in the text under "Compare Changes"
- Select your repository as base fork and their repo as head fork
- Create the pull request

That should work for you, even though I think it would be similar at command line level.